# Inequality involving irreducible fractions and constants

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions

Let $\frac m n$ be an irreducible fraction such that $1 \gt \sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \frac m n \gt 0$. Show that there is a constant $c \gt 0 \space$ such that
$$\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3 - \frac m n \gt \frac {1} {c \times n^4}$$ for every $n \gt 1.$

Comment: from where do you got this?

Comment: A Romanian magazine

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic, but by guess would be that this a consequence of [Liouville's theorem on diophantine approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Liouville_numbers_and_transcendence).

Comment: Of course, $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is an algebraic number of degree $4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is there a simpler proof for this particular case?

Comment: @M.Stefan: I do not think so. The continued fraction of the algebraic number $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is not that nice and its convergents have little to do with the convergents of $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$. But maybe I am wrong.